# Is there a way to implements a interface-like to functions arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking for a way to *standardize* the arrangement of arguments in TypeScript to make my application development more dynamic.

I have this class,

```
class A {
    static of (x: number, y: number) {
        return new A(x, y);
    }

    constructor (x: number, y: number) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to use something like this,

```
interface Args {
    (x: number, y: number): any;
}

class A {
    static of (<Args>) {
        return new A(x, y);
    }

    constructor (<Args>) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you might want to look into the Factory Pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible, but you can define the interface like object with properties and pass that instead:

```
interface Args {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

class A {
  of (args: Args) {
    return new A(args);
  }

  constructor (args: Args) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That's is a bit weird to me. What about (...args: Args)?